# Java class name as annotation attribute

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to use the simple name of a class inside an annotation? My aim is to get compile time safety for injections using JNDI names containing the class.

Example (of what I want to do, this fails at compile time):

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:module/" + MyService.class.getSimpleName())
private MyService myService;
```

class.getSimpleName() seems to be resolved at runtime, which does not work with annotations. Can I get it as a constant somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible the way you have it. It can be done with AOP techniques. But,

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:module/" + MyService.class.getSimpleName())
private MyService myService;
```

In this piece of code you seem to have only one possible value namely "MyService". It is not going to change dynamically, so why do you want to evaluate it dynamically?

Comment: If I at some point rename this class, I would like compile time safety. A string would have to be manually changed, while a reference to the class name would either be refactored automatically, or would give a compile timer error.